# Text Box Conditional Formatting - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a dashboard excel spreadsheet that has textboxes. In each text box is a formula pointing to a cell where a formula is applied to the raw data.

I am looking for a way to conditionally format the text boxes depending on either the value in the text box or the raw data behind if that's easier. Essentially if a textbox has a value over one I would like the font to be green if it is under I would like it to be red. I've had a hard time doing this so far and would appreciate anyones help. Below is my code so far but it wont run. I am a bit of a novice when it comes to VBA.

```
Sub Test_Change_Text()

If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value > ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("textbox 1")).Select
 With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 2).Font.Fill
  .Visible = msoTrue
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 2).Font.Fill
  .Visible = msoTrue
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
End With

End Sub
```

[image: screenshot dashboard]

Update: The code below is my final working code. This allows for three constraints.

```
Sub ChangeText()
    Dim shap As Shape

    For Each shap In Sheets("Output").Shapes
        If shap.Type = msoTextBox Then
            If IsNumeric(shap.TextEffect.Text) Then
                If shap.TextEffect.Text >= 3 Then
                    shap.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    If shap.TextEffect.Text <= -3 Then
                        shap.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        shap.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Next shap

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: can you please explain with some examples (or maybe screenshots) what you're trying to achive, because I can't understand anything from your explanation

Comment: If the number in the text box is a negative number make the font red. If it is positive make the number green. Sorry if I confused things. Those cells are text boxes so they cannot not be formatted through standard conditional formatting. I will need to develop a VBA solution.

Comment: Are these "textboxes" actually ActiveX textbox controls, or just shapes formatted as textboxes?

Comment: What do you mean by `Those cells are text boxes`?

Comment: Sorry I just meant that the numbers to the right of the line charts were standard text boxes. I think they are drawing objects but not sure. To get them I went to insert => text boxes. I apologize for not being able to explain this better but would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are regular textboxes (i.e. Insert > Text Box) you could try this

```
Sub ChangeText(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim shap As Shape
    For Each shap In sht.Shapes
        If shap.Type = msoTextBox Then
            If IsNumeric(shap.TextEffect.Text) Then
                With shap.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor
                If CDbl(shap.TextEffect.Text) > 0 Then
                    .RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    .RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next shap

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Brad! Both of your solutions were great but your macro was easy for me to understand!

Comment: @EdwardArmstrong casts the text to a `double` ensuring a valid comparison with 0. With your examples you could use `CInt` but I didn't know if you might have decimals. VBA does implicit type conversion but sometimes I like to be explicit about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "textboxes" are really shapes with linked text content:

```
Sub DoColor()

Dim shp As Shape, tmp

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        'only operate on linked shapes
        If Len(shp.DrawingObject.Formula) > 0 Then
            tmp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
            'ignore non-numeric values
            If IsNumeric(tmp) And Len(tmp) > 0 Then
                shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = _
                          IIf(tmp >= 0, vbGreen, vbRed)
            End If
        End If
    Next shp


End Sub
```

Comment: I've got to start using iif more. :)

Comment: Why test the length of `tmp`? If `IsNumeric` is true then does it matter that `Len` is?

Comment: Select an empty worksheet cell and run this in the Immediate window: `? IsNumeric(selection.value)`  I have been bitten by that in the past when checking cell values, so added it out of habit here: you are correct though it's not absolutely required in this case.

Comment: oh weird. yets `? IsNumeric("")`, `? IsNumeric(nothing)`, and `? IsNumeric(null)` are are all false. I guess it's a good check then!

Comment: Yes - the only catch is when reading from a worksheet: `? Cdbl(Selection.Value)` prints `0` if an empty cell is selected.

Comment: That is so strange. What IS the vlaue of an empty cell then? `?Cdbl("")` and `?Cdbl(null)` both give errors. How have I not come across this before?!