# Conditional formating of numeric value in Shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA

I have shapes in one work sheet which are referenced to second worksheet for % value.
I want to make numberic value in shape to be red if negative  else green.

I have checked [Text Box Conditional Formatting - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155936/text-box-conditional-formatting-excel-vba) here but could not find solution.

Comment: You link seems to point to the answer to your question - what problem did you have using one of those approaches?

Comment: What do you mean by "which are referenced to second worksheet for % value"? How do you use/set their value and in which circumstances would you like to change the font color. I mean, in which moment and triggered by what? Is it an event in the active sheet dealing with sheets in discussion values, or setting them?

Comment: If you edit your question and show us the code you used, we will maybe better understand what you really try accomplishing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.